# Hide product types in New product

Tags: product, admin, downloadable, virtual

I'm trying to find a way of stopping users in the back end of the site from adding certain product types.

I don't need to remove all the functionality of the product types I just need to remove the virtual and downloadable options from the new product page.

I've tried to find where this is in the back end with a lot of code digging but I'm not very up to date with the admin section of Magento as I am with building things for the front end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just happened to do the same for my gift-promo module, hide the gift product types, so here is my code, which you can adapt to your need.

I rewrite this via config.xml

....

```
    <catalog>
        <rewrite>
            <product_type>ProxiBlue_GiftPromo_Model_Product_Type</product_type>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog>  

  ....
```

any my class has this:

```
/**
 * Defines the gift type constant
 *
 * @category   ProxiBlue
 * @package    ProxiBlue_GiftPromo
 * @author     Lucas van Staden (support@proxiblue.com.au)
 */
class ProxiBlue_GiftPromo_Model_Product_Type extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type {

    const TYPE_GIFT = 'gift-';

    /**
     * Remove gift product type from admin display.
     * 
     * @return type
     */
    static public function getTypes() {
        if (is_null(self::$_types)) {
            $productTypes = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/catalog/product/type')->asArray();
            // remove gift type from admin displays
            //if(Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin() && array_key_exists(ProxiBlue_GiftPromo_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_GIFT, $productTypes)){
                unset($productTypes[ProxiBlue_GiftPromo_Model_Product_Type_Gift_Simple::TYPE_CODE]);    
                unset($productTypes[ProxiBlue_GiftPromo_Model_Product_Type_Gift_Configurable::TYPE_CODE]);
                unset($productTypes[ProxiBlue_GiftPromo_Model_Product_Type_Gift_Downloadable::TYPE_DOWNLOADABLE]);
            //}
            foreach ($productTypes as $productKey => $productConfig) {
                $moduleName = 'catalog';
                if (isset($productConfig['@']['module'])) {
                    $moduleName = $productConfig['@']['module'];
                }
                $translatedLabel = Mage::helper($moduleName)->__($productConfig['label']);
                $productTypes[$productKey]['label'] = $translatedLabel;
            }
            self::$_types = $productTypes;
        }

        return self::$_types;
    }

    /**
     * Here as the getTypes method will not be directly overwritten
     * 
     * @return type
     */
    static public function getOptionArray()
    {
        $options = array();
        foreach(self::getTypes() as $typeId=>$type) {
            $options[$typeId] = Mage::helper('catalog')->__($type['label']);
        }

        return $options;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this solve the issue? For example in the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer` the `getTypes` method is still called statically from the original class: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::getTypes()`. I'm asking because I'm just curious. I didn't try it.

Comment: The code is to only remove the display of The types from Admin, for Example in product create. The Fact That ind3xer still get Them, via its static call is a Good Thing.  This is why getoptionarray is extended to use the class own self::gettypes.

Comment: I made a new module that overwrites Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type and am tinkering in the getTypes function. Problem is I'm not sure what I need to unset to get this to work.

Comment: Hi, see class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type for the constants to the product types. Downloadables are in their own module, under the class Mage_Downloadable_Model_Product_Type

Answer (score 0):

**Note: This example is to show only one option, you can modify it according to your requirement.**

According to the question You only need to disable the options from drop down in Create Product Settings in admin.

you can do it this way:

1. In /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/footer.phtml at the end of file add the code:

First add php condition to affect the current page only.

```
 if($this->getRequest()->getActionName() == 'new'){ ?>
```

Then include latest jquey and add the below script.

```
 jQuery.noConflict();
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $('.adminhtml-catalog-product-new #product_type option[value=downloadable]').attr('selected','selected');
 });
```

Close the php condition.

2. Goto /skin/adminhtml/default/default/custom.css and css:

Add the css:

```
 #product_type > option {
    display: none;
}
#product_type > option:last-child {
    display: block;
}
```

It will show only downloadable option in the drop down.